# Proof of one of Minkowskis theorem's (geometry of numbers)

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Apparently the  following theorem;

Theorem: In $\Bbb R^2 $ we can be sure of a covering of at least $\lceil A \rceil$ lattice points where  is a measurable region of any shape and area A.

Can be used to prove Minkowski's theorem.

Let $\mathcal R$ be a region in the plane which is.

(i) Convex

(ii) Symmetric about the origin

(iii) Area > 4

Does anyone know the general process to doing such a thing and does it generalize to the larger dimensional cases?

My only real thought on how to do this is to look at a square of area 4 it contains only the origin then inscribe other convex entities inside it and make its area slightly bigger than 4. it is clearly intuitive that any other shape is less area efficient to lattice point containing than a square so if a square with more than area 4 does then everything should.

Comment: How can this theorem be true?  What if $A=\{(x,y)\mid .25\le x\le.5, 1\le  y\le 8\}?$  The area of $A$ is $2$ and it contains $0$ lattice points.

Comment: the theorem says you can place it in such a way that it contains at least 2 lattice points not that there isnt a placement that contains less. heres a proof of the theorem

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711258/blichtfeldts-theorem-in-higher-dimensions?rq=1

Comment: Thanks.  I was unfamiliar with the theorem, and couldn't understand it.

Comment: I find the wording of your theorem very confusing, with two capital A's...

Comment: Its entirely the reason this is a confusing argument one is under ideal placement the other is under the worse possible placement which makes me wonder how the proof goes.

Comment: I edited it for more clarity they are the same number sometimes and that how its listed in the textbook i found it in. its just saying whatever the area is take the integer portion rounded up  theres that many lattice points so the A's arent really different but they are i can see why your confused.

Comment: It is funny that you write Minkovaki instead of Minkowski.

Comment: Sorry my document is really hard to read it honestly looks like Minkowaki i copied it directly from the pdf lol. didnt know it was the same guy from quantum mechanics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, the goal is to prove Minkowski's Theorem using the above result. It works in any dimension $n\geq 2$. We will use:

Theorem: for any measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the intersection of the lattice with the translate $(v+A)\cap \mathbb{Z}^n$ contains at least $\lceil\mathcal{L}(A)\rceil$ points, where $\mathcal{L}$ stands for the Lebesgue measure.

Let $\mathcal{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex region, symmetric, of area $>2^n$. Consider the set $A=\mathcal{R}/2$ (the image under homothety of ratio 1/2). So the area of $A$ is $>1$. So there are two points $x\neq y \in \mathbb{Z}^n\cap(v+A)$. Then $x,y$ can be written:
$$x=v+a/2, \; y=v+b/2,$$
where $a,b \in \mathcal{R}$. Since $\mathcal{R}$ is symmetric, $-b$ is also in $\mathcal{R}$. So
$$x-y=\frac{a+(-b)}2,$$
is a nonzero point with integer coordinates (since $x\neq y$), and the barycenter of the two points $a,-b$ of $\mathcal{R}$, so also in $\mathcal{R}$ by convexity, as required.

Comment: Great answer was really lost how one would use the theorem but you spelled it out clearly.

Comment: I agree : very thorough answer.